# Rails "application.js requires" and AJAX double request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am running a rails app with AJAX, but all of my AJAX form submits (via remote: true) are being sent twice. I only have one:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

In my application layout, so I dont think Im including everything twice (as I have read may be the issue).

I am using twitter bootstrap and a jcrop module to trim photos.

Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery.Jcrop
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Is there anything in here that could be causing my AJAX links to shoot off twice??

Comment: I removed rails-ujs and this appears to have cleaned up my problem. Am I going to have issues without this later? Or have I covered myself with these other includes?

Comment: You want either `jquery_ujs`, or `rails-ujs`, not both. They're functionally the same, the former being dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling JS into the application twice, I just had the same problem. Remove the following line from application.js.

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

.